# C# DateTime to be copied without format getting changed

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date and time which should be copied to DateTime object without changing its format.
Is there a way to resolve it?

Pls see the code below

```
string dateTime = "07/20/11 14:40:28";
DateTime copyDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
string dateTime2 = copyDateTime.ToString();
```

Output:

{7/20/2011 2:40:28 PM}

If you notice the output, it got changed to PM. I want it as it is. How to get it?

EDIT:
I want dateTime2 to have the value exactly as it was for dateTime.

Comment: A `DateTime` has no format, it has just a value. A string can have a format. What you're probably seeing is the output of the debugger, does that matter?

Comment: Are you sure your second line doesn't throw any exception?

Answer (score 4):

Format is not intrinsically associated with the `DateTime`. Format is simply a display property.

If you need to display it in your preferred format than simply call:

```
Console.WriteLine(copyDateTime.ToString("G"));
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for a complete list of standard format strings.

Answer (score 0):

Before outputting, you need to convert the DateTime back into a string. By default, it simply calls "ToString" which uses the default DateTime format configured for the current user/locale.

Use ToString and specify a format to convert the datetime back into a String, then you can control the format.